# Restore Music Folder & Shortcut

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, files, music

I was sorting out my music collection and accidentally deleted my (empty) ~/Music folder. Now, there is no shortcut in the Files/Nautilus sidebar, and if I create a new ~/Music, I am unable to restore its shortcut and folder icon.

How can I restore this default behaviour for the ~/Music folder?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to get it working by deleting the following folders:

```
~/.local/share/nautilus
~/.config
~/.gconf
~/.gnome2
~/.gnome2_private
```

It's possible that I only needed to delete one or two of these folders, but hey, it worked!

I just now need to open up `dconf-editor` again and reset my Rhythmbox settings and set up Ubuntu One again, but still, I have my music icons back.

Make sure you know what you're doing if you want to attempt this too!

Answer (score 0):

[This should help you.](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.in/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-adding-bookmarksshortcuts.html)

For a short summary, you need to open nautilus, go to files in the main menu and then under bookmarks you should see the folders bookmarked there, you will be able to create folder for you ~/Music folder there.